# Drag a view and drop it over another view

Tags: android

I've followed the drag and drop tutorial from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html, and now I need to detect if the user is droping the view over another one to combine the data from both views.

How can I detect this? It cannot be a simple collision detection because the view can collide with more than one different views, so the user must place it centered to the other view.

UPDATE

Here is the code that I'm using. When I drag and drop a button, I cannot allow it to be dropped in a blank area of the container (GridLayout). How can I fix this?

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mButton1;
    private Button mButton2;
    private Button mButton3;
    private Button mButton4;
    private Button mButton5;
    private Button mButton6;
    private Button mButton7;
    private Button mButton8;
    private Button mButton9;
    private Button mButton10;
    private Button mButton11;
    private Button mButton12;
    private Button mButton13;
    private Button mButton14;
    private Button mButton15;
    private Button mButton16;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadReferences();
        setEventHandlers();
    }

    private void setEventHandlers() {
        mButton1.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton2.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton3.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton4.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton5.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton6.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton7.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton8.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton9.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton10.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton11.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton12.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton13.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton14.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton15.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        mButton16.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

        mButton1.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton2.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton3.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton4.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton5.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton6.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton7.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton8.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton9.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton10.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton11.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton12.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton13.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton14.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton15.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        mButton16.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    }

    private void loadReferences() {
        mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        mButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        mButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        mButton7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        mButton8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        mButton9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        mButton10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        mButton11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        mButton12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        mButton13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        mButton14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
        mButton15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
        mButton16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
    }

    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((Button)view).getText(), 1000).show();

                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
public class ShapeDragDrop extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,
        OnDragListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shape_drag_drop);
        findViewById(R.id.red_ball).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.green_ball).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.blue_ball).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.top_container).setOnDragListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.bottom_container).setOnDragListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
            View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout to = (LinearLayout) v;
            to.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }

}


buleball.xml like shape in drawable folder.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#0000FF" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#800000FF"
        android:startColor="#FF0000FF" />

</shape>


layout.xml


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Drag-N-Drop Demo"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/red_ball"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/red_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/green_ball"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/green_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blue_ball"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_ball" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have the following code: https://gist.github.com/julianonunes/f29e279851ec313edcb3 . If I drag the button to an empty area of my GridLayout it is also considering as valid drop location. How can I fix this?